# Android: How to choose background image for the layout

Tags: android

We have a requirement that we need to provide the customer with three backgrounds to choose from. All of the icons and widgets remain the same in all the screens. At the time of installation, the user would have the option to select which background they preferred. Any suggestions on how to do this? But with my current level of knowledge I don't really know how to do this. Maybe someone with more experience knows a solution or at least some pointers to start?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you would have to have the user select the background and then store an id for the background in shared preferences http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref . Then when the application launches, check the shared preferences for the background ID and set the background for the Layout in the onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

Just pop up a dialog stating a condition related to the theme at splash screen itself,have a value assigned for all the theme condition.Now set the background programmatically depending on the condition.Use preference to store value & get it.Here is how you set image

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
  image.setImageResource(R.drawable.test2);

//Set Preference
```

SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor;
prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
prefsEditor.putString("ANYNAME", your_value_to_be_stored_here);
prefsEditor.commit();

//Get Preferenece
SharedPreferences myPrefs;
myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
String getstring=myPrefs.getString("ANYNAME", "");

Comment: Hey Kavi I have added the ways to add & get preference above,please make use of it..

Answer (score 0):

At the time of installation? Does that mean when the customer is installing your app? if just when the customer open your app first,pop up a dialog to let the customer make a choice and then use Shared Preferences to store the value

Answer (score 0):

Use the way that Karthic said, but for simplicity, just save the `int` value of the resour image which user has been selected. I mean `int r = R.drawable.something`.